# When adding css menu drop down on hover, it makes a lot of free space on the template

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

When trying to add an box with content inside it on a menu on a hover "drop down menu", it does something like this:

[image]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/9d055e63b06c6770cca6382fda7e5d34.png))</sub>

I want the drop down to popup when I hover on the categories menu item.

This is the code I used for it:

```
       <div class="secondheader">

      <div class="container">

               <div class="span12">

                          <ul class="nav6">

                          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>

                          <li class="dropdown1"><a href="#">Categories</a> </li>

                          <li><a href="#">Buy</a></li>

                          <li><a href="#">Sell</a></li>

                          <li><a href="#">Forums</a></li>

                          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>

                          <li><a href="#">item 1</a></li>

                          <li><a href="#">Forums</a></li>

                          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>

                          <li><a href="#">item 1</a></li>

                          </ul>

                          </div>

               </div>

       </div>

</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.secondheader {
background-image: url("../img/second.png");
width: 100%;
height: 66px;
border-bottom: solid 6px #f0e8ce;
}    

.nav6  {
list-style: none;
font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
float: left
font-size: 20px;
margin-top: 13px;
margin-left: -35px;
}

.nav6  li {
display: inline;
margin: 0px;
font-size: 18px;
font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
float: left;
margin-top: 10px;
}

.nav6 a {
color: #7d7253;
padding-top: 20px;
padding-bottom: 20px;
padding-left: 20px;
padding-right: 20px;
}

.nav6 a:hover {
background-image: url("../img/hoverbg.png");
color: #53410f;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

I've tried using tutorials but I don't really understand on how to make the same thing for my layout I mean it has different ways and classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want something like http://jsfiddle.net/b76Qc/?

**Edit:**

In your case the submenu is horizontal because you use descendant selectors instead of child selectors:

replace `.nav6 li` with `.nav6>li` and `.nav6 li ul` with `.nav6>li>ul`

See my jsfiddle if you want the complete code.

**Edit 2:**

If you want each element to have a different background,

```
<li class="dropdown1"><a href="#">Categories</a>
    <ul>
        <li style="background:red"><a href="#">Buy</a></li>
        <li style="background:blue"><a href="#">Sell</a></li>
        <li style="background:green"><a href="#">Forums</a></li>
        ...
    </ul>
</li>
```

But can you provide a link to your site instead of images? The square shown in http://gyazo.com/35835f003d0d8b776248196632cc1d4a.png is weird, but I can't know what's happening just with images...

**Edit 3:**

You have to change

```
.nav6 a {
    color: #7D7253;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

into

```
.nav6>li>a {
    padding: 20px;
}
.nav6 a {
    color: #7D7253;
}
```

And

```
.nav6 a:hover {
    background-image: url("../img/hoverbg.png");
    color: #53410F;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

into

```
.nav6 a:hover {
    color: #53410F;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.nav6 > li > a:hover {
    background-image: url("../img/hoverbg.png");
}
```

**Edit 4:**

Sorry I didn't explain why I was telling you to use selectors with `>`, I thought you knew it.

Your html is like this:

```
<ul class="nav6">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown1"><a href="#">Categories</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Buy</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sell</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Forums</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Forums</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">item 1</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

If you use `.nav6 a`, the style will be applied to all `<a>` inside `.nav6`. That's a **descendant selector**.

Then, this will be applied both to menu's links and submenu's links:

`<ul class="nav6">`

`<li>`**`<a href="#">Home</a>`**`</li>`

`<li class="dropdown1">`**`<a href="#">Categories</a>`**

`<ul>`

`<li>`**`<a href="#">Buy</a>`**`</li>`

`<li>`**`<a href="#">Sell</a>`**`</li>`

`...`

`</ul>`

`</li>`

`</ul>`

But if you use a **child selector** like `.nav6>li>a`, the style is applied only to the links which are childs of a `<li>` which is a child of `.nav6` (only menu's links). This way we can set which styles we want to apply to all links and which to menu's links:

`<ul class="nav6">`

`<li>`**`<a href="#">Home</a>`**`</li>`

`<li class="dropdown1">`**`<a href="#">Categories</a>`**

`<ul>`

`<li><a href="#">Buy</a></li>`

`<li><a href="#">Sell</a></li>`

`...`

`</ul>`

`</li>`

`</ul>`

**Edit 5:**

To fix the problem with backgrounds,

change

```
.nav6 a:hover {
    color: #53410F;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

to

```
.nav6>li:hover>a, .nav6 .dropdown1 li:hover>a {
    color: #53410F;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

and

```
.nav6 > li > a:hover
    background-image: url("../img/hoverbg.png");
}
```

to

```
.nav6>li:hover>a {
    background-image: url("../img/hoverbg.png");
}
```

Comment: Exactly but now it does this:
http://gyazo.com/d6316d622686812f81d7ce920fbf6d87.png
I want it to go down instead, not linear.

Comment: Thank you, but now what it does is this: 
http://gyazo.com/35835f003d0d8b776248196632cc1d4a.png

Currently it takes the background from nav 6, i want each item to have it's own background, how do I do it?

Comment: I provided a link, I still need help to remove that background.

Comment: Thanks, the background is gone, but as you see it's still looking weird when you hover on the links I mean it's not exactly changing color when you're hovering on a specify item, Example if you hover on home inside the drop down, it will change color to the second item, how do I fix it? Once again thanks!

Comment: @Jony That's because you have `.nav6 a {color: #7D7253;padding: 20px;}`. Replace it with `.nav6>li>a{padding: 20px;} .nav6 a{color: #7D7253;}`.

Comment: Thanks all worked!
two questions:

What does > selectors do? I haven't understood exactly, could you please explain abit more easier of what it does?

Also, if I got everything solved, how do I close my question or something?

Thanks man, working perfect now.

Comment: How do I make the shadow go like this: http://gyazo.com/e25aa288d19264ca019caf16ac8d97c7.png?1345416690.png

At the moment, it doesnt work like this, http://justxp.plutohost.net/survive/index.html

Also, why whenever I stop hovering on the menu that gave me the drop down, the bg goes off like this: http://gyazo.com/20c9ea451a8c2802d80229d5b2bd7af3

Shouldn't the categories menu hover bg stay whenever u go hover the drop down? thanks

Comment: It's going off topic now, Im going to open a new question regarding to this because I have more questions about this. thank you.

Comment: @Jony I have edited my answer with an explanation and the fix for the background problem

Answer (score 0):

To show you how little code is actualy required to make this work i set up a small example here: http://jsfiddle.net/fS5WV/

I put the explanations in the css.

The key lies in nesting the menu's properly, and giving the submenus a position absolute to prevent them from pushing the content down.

I hope it makes sense. Feel free to ask if you need further explanation.